# Replace the directory of an image src, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'd like to replace the directory of an image `src`, changing `.*pinterest.com/192/` to `.*pinterest.com/550/`.

I had been trying to modify this code to change the directory name instead of just removing the "_b" part of the filename.

```
document.getElementById("chrome")
.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (a) {
if (a.target.tagName && a.target.tagName == "DIV" && /entry\s?/.test(a.target.className)) {
    var b = a.target.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var c in b) {
        var d = b[c];
        if (/.*pinterest\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test(d.src)) {
            d.style.width = d.style.height = "inherit";
            d.src = d.src.replace(/_b\.(\w+)$/, ".$1")
        }
    }
}
}, false)
```

Comment: Can you unminify this code first?

Comment: Sorry about that. Changed the original post. Hopefully that's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some issues/questions:

1. It's not clear if you want to change *both* the `_b` and the `192`.  Do you?  If so, please link to a page that has this kind of image.
2. [`DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events), and it is not a good idea to use it.
3. Where is that `document.getElementById ("chrome")` coming from?  That seems suspicious and, if this is for Pinterest pages, there is no node with the id `chrome` on the pages I checked.  **Link to the target page(s) you are trying to modify**.
4. For Pinterest, you also need to reset the `max-width` CSS for your new image size to take effect.

Your code refactored to replace the 192 in just the path is:

```
document.getElementById ("chrome").addEventListener (
    "DOMNodeInserted",
    function (zEvent) {
        var newNode = zEvent.target;
        if (
               newNode.tagName  &&  newNode.tagName == "DIV"
            && /entry\b/i.test (newNode.className)
        ) {
            var images = newNode.getElementsByTagName ("img");
            for (var J in images) {
                var image = images[J];
                if (    /pinterest\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test (image.src)
                    ||  /pinterest\.com\/192\//.test (image.src)
                ) {
                    image.style.width   = "inherit";
                    image.style.height  = "inherit";
                    image.src           = image.src.replace (/_b\.(\w+)$/, ".$1");
                    image.src           = image.src.replace (/\.com\/192\//, ".com/550/");
                }
            }
        }
    },
    false
);
```

---

---

But, taking into account issues 2, 3, and 4; **a *complete script* that actually works on Pinterest** is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Pinterest, resize thumbnails
// @include  http://pinterest.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#ColumnContainer a.PinImage img.PinImageImg", resizeThumbnails);

function resizeThumbnails (jNode) {
    var imgSrc  = jNode.attr ("src");

    if (/pinterest\.com\/192\//.test (imgSrc) ) {
        jNode.css ( {
            width:          "inherit",
            height:         "inherit",
            "max-width":    "550px"
        } );
        jNode.attr ("src", imgSrc.replace (/\.com\/192\//, ".com/550/") );
    }
}
```

Note that additional styling and layout mod is needed, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: For what I was trying to do, both versions of your code work perfectly just as you wrote them. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, testing it again just the first version worked, but that's fine. The script was being used to replace the images in Pinterest feeds inside Google Reader. Previously the difference between thumbs and larger images was just the "_b" at the end of the filename, but they recently changed it to being the same filename in a different directory. With the code you wrote, both the old format and new format show up as larger images now.

Comment: Okay.  Since I didn't know what site you were running the script on, I took a guess that it was Pinterest.  So, for the second version of the code, I removed those bits that aren't used on Pinterest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at understanding and modifying code it's easiest to break it down into steps so you understands what it's doing.

For instance, in this code-line you have both if statements and loops that only complicate the matter.

Starting from scratch let's presume you know how to get the initial URL string.

```
var string = '.*pinterest.com/192/';
```

Now we can use a substring method to take it back to the second last forward-slash.  With javascript the two methods we'll be using are

```
string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)
```

and

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

Combine them as so:

```
string = string.substring(0, string.substring('//');
```

You'll notice I've escaped the forward slash with another so it can be identified instead of parsed.
This should set string = ".*pinterest.com/";

So now you can add your own directory on the end.

```
string += '550/';
```

---

---

RE:

> Any idea what the code would look like to change image filenames from something like:
>   `http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/192/24/4c/a5/244ca513d930a9f21fd89e8455948a49.jpg`
>   to
>   `http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/550/24/4c/a5/244ca513d930a9f21fd89e8455948a49.jpg`?

I'll answer your second question here as the comment won't allow me to multi-line.

```
var s1 = string.substring(0, string.substring('//'));
var s2 = string.substring(string.substring('//')+1);
string = s1+'550/'+s2;
```

[Reference for `indexOf()`.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Comment: My knowledge of Javascript isn't very good. Any idea what the code would look like to change image filenames from something like http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/192/24/4c/a5/244ca513d930a9f21fd89e8455948a49.jpg to http://media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com/550/24/4c/a5/244ca513d930a9f21fd89e8455948a49.jpg ?

Comment: Same principal applies.  If you know the url it's easiest.  You can copy the url after the section you want to join into another variable, and append it after you've changed the '550' directory.

Comment: I'm trying to change all instances of where 192 appears with 550 in the image urls on a page.

Comment: ah then you can use string.indexOf(192)